# Why am I getting the 500 Internal Server Error message?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a total newbie to python, CGI, and HTML.

My current project is coding an Ubuntu web server. Some of my basic forms are functional, but other scripts give me an "Internal Server Error" messages in my web browser.

The following python script ripped straight from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm is supposed to repeat the option you selected in the drop-down menu, but instead I receive an "Internal Server Error" message:

HTML file named "dropdown.html" stored in `/var/www/html`

```
<form action = "/cgi-bin/dropdown.py" method = "post" target = "_blank">
<select name = "dropdown">
<option value = "Maths" selected>Maths</option>
<option value = "Physics">Physics</option>
</select>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
</form>
```

Python file named "dropdown.py" stored in /usr/lib/cgi-bin

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
if form.getvalue('dropdown'):
   subject = form.getvalue('dropdown')
else:
   subject = "Not entered"

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Dropdown Box - Sixth CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2> Selected Subject is %s</h2>" % subject
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

My `/var/log/apache2/error.log` report reads as follows:

> [Date] [cgi:error] [pid123:tid 123456789]  [cgid:error] (2)No such file or directory: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/dropdown.py' failed
>
> [Date] [cgi:error] [pid123:tid 123456789] [client 192.168.xxx.xxx:57102] End of script output before headers: dropdown.py, referer: http://192.168.xxx.xxx/dropdown.html

Any idea where I should be looking at to fix this 500 Internal Server Error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Look close at the error message: `/us/lib/cgi-bin/dropdown.py` Why **/us/**?  You got a typo somewhere.

Comment: It seems more likely that it's `/usr/lib` (note the `r`) rather than `/us/lib` (no `r`).

Comment: If it were my keyboard the typo would be `/sr/` because the letter 'u' sticks for some reason :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. That was a typo on my end in recreating the error.log. The error long entry does in fact read /usr/lib

Comment: Well it still looks like apache cannot not find dropdown.py. What happens if you execute as root: `su - apache -c /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dropdown.py` and you should double check that `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/dropdown.py` does actually exists.

Comment: I couldn't get `apache` to work, but I did execute `apache2 -c /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dropdown.py`
It output:
[Sun Nov 25 03:38:28.620247 2018] [core:warn] [pid 40157] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot

Comment: You may be on to something.  You should probably write a very simple cgi like the classic `printenv` cgi that comes with apache installs and see if you can get that to work.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I will admit, though, that I am lost. What does the `apache -c /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dropdown.py` command do? I can see that my dropdown.py script does exist in the /usr/lib/cgi-bin directory, too.

And I am unfamiliar with `printenv` cgi scripts. But I appreciate you regardless.

Comment: Sounds like you have an apache config issue. Do you have any control of the apache config? and if this is an apache config issue SO is for the forum for you.

Comment: I have full control over the apache config. It's Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 Virtual Machine. I've installed apache2 on the machine, but not apache.

Is the problem with my script is that it's trying to use apache, and not apache2?

Comment: No I don't think that is a problem.  If I were you I'd try remove your script, `dropdown.py` from the equation by seeing if you can get any CGI scripts working on your apache2 server.